# automatically populate text box based on select entry

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way within php to get a value picked up from database automatically?

Basically, If I have a select box & I select option "Laptop-01" , is there a way within PHP to check the database for that row and then automatically pick up the serial number of Laptop-01 and populate it within the text box for the devices serial number.

At the moment I've just got two text boxes and user would need to manually enter both the product number (Laptop-01) & then the serial number.

I've currently got the following code;

PHP

```
<?php

$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `loanproducts`";
$selectresult = mysqli_query($connection, $selectquery);

$selectusersquery = "SELECT * FROM `loanusers`";
$selectusersresult = mysqli_query($connection, $selectusersquery);

if (isset($_POST['editloan'])): 

$loanid = $_POST["loanid"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$product=$_POST["product"];
$product_desc=$_POST["product_desc"];
$serial=$_POST["serial"];
$date_collected=$_POST["date_collected"];
$date_return = $_POST["date_return"];
$returned = $_POST["returned"];



    $edit_query="UPDATE loans SET 
                username = '$username',
                product = '$product',
                product_desc = '$product_desc',
                serial = '$serial',
                date_collected ='$date_collected',
                date_return = '$date_return',
                returned = '$returned'
                WHERE loanid ='$loanid'"; 
    $edit_result= mysqli_query($connection, $edit_query);

    if ($edit_result) :
            header ('location: editloan.php?confirm=Loan successfully updated');
        else :
            echo "<b>This didn`t work, error: </b>";
            echo mysqli_error($connection);
    endif;

endif;


$loanid=$_GET['loanid']; 

$my_query="select * from loans where loanid=$loanid";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);


while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

    $username = $myrow["username"];
    $product = $myrow["product"];
    $product_desc = $myrow["product_desc"];
    $serial = $myrow["serial"];
    $date_collected=$myrow["date_collected"];
    $date_return=$myrow["date_return"];
    $returned=$myrow["returned"];


endwhile;



?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<h2 align="center">Edit Product Form</h2>
<body>
<div id="loginp"<p align="center">Edit this loan for the Coleg Sir Gar Loan System</p></div>
<form method="POST" action="editloaninfo.php">

<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Username:</label><select name="username" style="width: 150px">
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($selectusersresult))
  { if ( $row1[1] == $username )
         $selected = "selected";
    else $selected = "";
    echo "<option $selected>{$row1[1]}</option>";
  }?>
</select></p></div>

<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Product:</label><select name="product" style="width: 150px">
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($selectresult))
  { if ( $row1[1] == $product )
         $selected = "selected";
    else $selected = "";
    echo "<option $selected>{$row1[1]}</option>";
  }?>
</select></p></div>


<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Product Description:</label><input  class="inputform" type="text" name="product_desc" placeholder="Product  Description..." autocomplete="off" required size="18" value="<?php echo  $product_desc; ?>"></p></div>


<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Serial Number:</label><input class="inputform" type="text" name="serial" placeholder="Serial Number..." autocomplete="off" required size="18" value="<?php echo $serial; ?>"></p></div>


<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Date Collected:</label><input class="inputform" type="date" name="date_collected" autocomplete="off" size="30" value="<?php echo $date_collected; ?>"></p></div>


<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Date Returned:</label><input class="inputform" type="date" name="date_return" autocomplete="off" size="30" value="<?php echo $date_return; ?>"></p></div>


<div id="editp"><p align="center">
<label class="labelform">Returned:</label><select name="returned" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="Yes" <?php echo $returned === 'Yes' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="No" <?php echo $returned === 'No' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>No</option>
</select></p></div>

<br>

<input type="hidden"  name=loanid value= "<?php echo $loanid; ?>" >

<div id="editp"><input class="inputform" type="submit" name="editloan" value="Save Changes">
<input class="inputform" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="window.location.href='editloan.php'"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like there's a bit too much code here, making your question harder to read. Could you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do is :

When User  select 'Laptop-01' you page must update all INPUTS with information related to user's laptop (like Serial number).This can be done by **adding [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)**

Please note : This answer will give you idea about how to **Populate data from data base** then you can do this for any information you needed.

```
<form>
<select id='product_name' onchange="get_data()">
<option value='Laptop-01'>Laptop-01</option>
</select>
<input name='serial_no' id='serial_no'> 
<input name='product_no' id='product_no'> 


</form>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function get_data(){

//In very short what this do is :
//get values 
var serial_no = document.getElementById('product_name').value;

//create an Object
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "yourpage.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

                //ajax.responsetex is things you echo from script next to it
                var index1 = ajax.responseText.split(",");
                //index1 is array holding values 
                //index1[0]=$serial_no
                //index1[1]=$product_no
                //Now set value of your serian_no INPUT to $serial_no = index1[0];
                document.getElementById('serial_no').value = index1[0];
document.getElementById('product_no').value = index1[1]

        }
    }
//ajax.send = POST/GET method 
    ajax.send("product_name="+product_name);
}
 </script>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['product_name'])){

$sql = "SELECT serial_no,product_no FROM loanuser WHERE username='$username'";
$query = ($connection , $query);

while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$serial_no = $myrow["serial_no"];
$product_no = $myrow["product_no"];
}
//form a (,) separated list and echo it. 
echo $serial_no.",".$product_no;

exit();
}
?>
```

Ajax.js

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open(meth, url, true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
    return true;    
}
}
```

**If you want me to add more explanation on AJAX used in this page , please add request in comment section i will edit it to more better answer**

Comment: Please Upvote and mark as answer if this answer is correct . . .